# stretched generated thumbnail in my blog - how to fix it?

Tags: thumbnails, stretched

I created a blog using blogger.com but am having difficulty:

- Whenever I create a post, it creates an automatic thumbnail of the image that I did upload. The problem is: the thumbnails are being generated stretched / distorced (it aren't keeping the aspect ratio).

Is there anything I can do to fix this? My blog url = http://fabianamakeupartist.blogspot.com.br/

(I'm practically lay in programming, I only know a little about html, which allowed me to edit the blog a bit. Sorry if I am asking the question in the wrong place and sorry for my bad english).

Thanks a lot for any help.
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to advanced feature under custom template blogger and add your own css for post thumbnail to fix the problem.